Is there any BETTER & CLEAN way to use SAF (Storage Access Framework) in Flutter?
Actually I wanted to create a file downloader in Flutter for android which can download file concurrently. For that I want an access to the storage system or any folder on disk which is selected by user. I tried using Filepicker package in flutter but it works in some devices but not in some(also with using including the permission for storage management in manifest file).
I tried to create a simple platform native code using kotlin and get a path user selected using
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FOLDER_PICKER && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            data?.data?.let { uri ->
                contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(
                    uri,
                    Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
                )

                // Convert the URI to a file path
                val folderPath = getAbsolutePathFromUri(uri) ?: ""

                // Send the folder path back to the Flutter side
                pendingResult?.success(folderPath)
                pendingResult = null
            }
        } else {
            // If the user cancels the folder picker, send an empty string back
            pendingResult?.success("")
            pendingResult = null
        }
    }

But it returns the value in form of 'tree/downloads' which is not working either and I also formatted this path to /storage/emulated/0/Downloads it still arouse and Permission denied error.
So, I want to know if anyone of you know about how to access the storage system in better way that could work on most of the android devices and very predictive way. (not just random like sometime works and sometimes not and without mentioning full storage access in manifest.)

Updates file picker is good but if that's now working try using flutter_file_dialog or ext_storage for folder access.

yeah I used flutter_file_dialog which seem working but it returns the same  path like content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/tree/downloads which doesn't seem any valid dir to me where i can save multiple parts of the file and then join them (mean proper file path with permission to write.) another one ext_storage is already outdated I guess almost 2 years from last update.

No ext_storage last updated 30 days ago please have a look and if you feel answer is helpfull please vote up. Thanks

yeah sure if it will help then i will upvote but the problem is still there and about you are saying ext_storage being updated 30 days ago i found package ext_path which is updated 30 days ago and it provide some paths like download and other but have no option to gain the access permission of it i want to gain persistent permission for that folder also (SAF). So I guess it is not the right answer.

then I think first you have to use permission handler after getting storage permission you have to define that path of storage.

I already tried with permission handler since it give the  permission to whole storage so i don't know about how to get the permission for path if you then tell me?
